# jQuery on() with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to 'ajaxify' standard links. I am using the jQuery on() function to intercept the click and retrieve the content dynamically:

```
$('.nextLink').on("click", function(e) {
    url = $(this).attr( 'href' ).replace( /^#/, '' );
    $.get(url, null, function(response) {
        $('#searchResults').replaceWith(response);
    });
});
```

This works fine except that the standard link behavior still occurs so I get the content using ajax but then it's wiped by a full page refresh. I tried returning false from the handler to prevent the normal submit

```
$('.nextLink').on("click", function(e) {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

This works however I also have links in the content which is loaded by ajax. My understanding is that jQuery's on() function should rebind the handlers for content loaded using ajax however it seems adding `return false` prevents this happening.

So it seems i am in a catch-22 situation, I can either allow the event bubbling to occur which allows 'on()' to work correctly however I also get a non-ajax submit, or I can prevent the standard submit but this breaks `on()`

Can someone tell me the best way to handle this situation?

Many thanks

Comment: Do the `.nextLink` elements only ever appear within `#searchResults` ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you could'nt have figured this out on you own by reading the documentation or searching for the four billion other questions on SO about the exact same thing ?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, as suggested I am attaching on() to the parent element (searchResults) then using the selector to select links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...This works fine except that the standard link behavior still occurs so I get the content using ajax but then it's wiped by a full page refresh...

Use `preventDefault()` to stop the default action

```
$('.nextLink').on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
```

to also bind the handler on new added elements you need to use event delegation to capture the click event on a parent element of `.nextLink`, e.g. with

```
 $('#searchResults').on("click", ".nextLink", function(e) ...
```

See on() usage on [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You want your document to listen to `.nextLink` links, wether they were present at the very beginning or not:

```
$(document).on("click", '.nextLink', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    url = $(this).attr( 'href' ).replace( /^#/, '' );
    $.get(url, null, function(response) {
        $('#searchResults').replaceWith(response);
    });

});
```

This way you listen to events on `.nextLink`, no matter when they've been created - check [jQuery on() docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to re-register the `click` handler on the newly loaded content so that you don't have to use event delegation:

```
function doload(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    url = $(this).attr( 'href' ).replace( /^#/, '' );
    $.get(url).done(function(response) {
        $('#searchResults').replaceWith(response);
        $('#searchResults .nextLink').on('click', doload);  // re-register new content
    });
}

$('.nextLink').on('click', doload);
```